# cloudera manager can't stop or delete any service

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, cloudera-manager

Following error is seen when no matter stop or delete any service such as oozie, yarn, hbase etc... Can anyone help?

```
A server error has occurred. Send the following information to Cloudera.

Path: http://172.29.36.58:7180/cmf/services/2/do

Version: Cloudera Standard 4.7.2 (#135 built by jenkins on 20130918-2007 git: 72d3f9dfa797fe2c627d00dc6414a1e0151b91d6)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:Service my_hbase1 (my_hbase) has unsatisfied dependencies: [ZOOKEEPER]
at Preconditions.java line 92
in com.google.common.base.Preconditions checkArgument()
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  Install Zookeeper and configure your HBase service to point to your configured Zookeeper instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved. This is because the incorrect configuration for Service my_hbase1 (my_hbase). Corrected the configuration of Zookeeper to the right name and the issue is gone.